# How to hide the default HTML attach folder button; but use the function in our custom button

Tags: angular

How can i use the attach folder function (HTML) 
on a custtom button made by component.

```
This is the area where we have the issue:
<app-button doButtonClass="btn btn-dark btn-fw btn-rounded btn-fw" 
doButtonName=" Cargar Archivo Bancos" 
doButtonIcon='mdi mdi-bank float-left'
(click)="goCargarArchivoBancos()">
</app-button>

<input  type='file' (change)="fileChanged($event)" hide=true>
```

The button is made by component and the code is this:

```
<button  type="button" class="{{doButtonClass}}">
{{doButtonName}} 
<i class="{{doButtonIcon}}"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get What exactly you want. but you can hide an element by setting its Opacity and you still use its functionality.

```
.hide-it {
    opacity: 0:
}
```

now you can simply trigger click event of that button when clicked on your component button.